# Is it possible to chang geonodes Extrude Mesh for a face "Origin" to other position?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces, extrude, origin, point-clouds

I'm using Blender 3.4.1. I'm learning geonodes. I wanted to use Geo Proximity to control Extrude Mesh on different faces. But I find that some face like "L shape" has the origin point in the middle of the missing faces rather than on the L face itself. Here's the image for example.
[image: Extrude Mesh - Face origin point]

As the image 3 shown. Although the point can be Set Position to the location I wanted but the extrude mesh still hover in the middle of the invisible face.

Is it possible to set the face origin point to new position?
So that Effector pick up the Extrude Mesh effect perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: The face's "origin point" is not an origin point like an object origin which can be located anywhere in relation to the mesh. The face's center point is as the name suggests, the center of the face - it is dependent on the shape of the face and cannot be changed manually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps I need figure it out with alternative way.